# How to create `Object` key from iteration variables for IE browsers?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to loop a json and creating new set of array. it works fine with other than `ie` browser. how to fix this for `ie`

her is my code :

```js
var json = [{
    "name": "techM",
    "age": 12,
    "station": "chennai"
  },
  {
    "name": "CTS",
    "age": 10,
    "station": "Pondy"
  }
];

var columns = [];

json.forEach(function(object) {

  var that = this;

  Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
    //[key] is not understand by ie browsers.
    if (!that[key]) that[key] = {
      [key]: []
    }, columns.push(that[key]);
    that[key][key].push(object[key])

  })
  console.log(that);
}, {})
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rvtw7jqp/)

Comment: Do you really want an object inside your objects ?

Comment: JSON is a notation, your "*json*" is an array literal. What version of IE? Which part is returning an error? [*forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [*Object.keys*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) are IE 9+. MDN has polyfills.

Comment: The way you construct your array is weird. The input has 2 objects, you create 2 objects and each one has all the properties of all the input. So you basically get two duplicate objects - maybe that's what you intended? Not sure.

Comment: I am converting `json` objects to arrays based on object lables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not work in IE is the computed object property:

```
that[key] = {[key]: []}
```

This is not supported in IE as described towards the bottom of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

You could change this to

```
var obj = {};
obj[key] = [];
if(!that[key]) that[key] = obj, columns.push(that[key]);
that[key][key].push(object[key])
```

Updated live example: https://jsfiddle.net/rvtw7jqp/1/

Comment: @RobG - Jamiec answer is exactly correct. it fix the issue. there is nothing to down vote him.

Comment: @user2024080—it was not my down vote. The poor formatting of the OP meant I missed the object passed as the *thisArg*. You only need to click the *Tidy* button to get neat code. Also, your style of using commas to put multiple statements on one line and omitting blocks makes the code harder to read than it needs to be.

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like this.

```
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = function(obj) {
    var keys = [];

    for (var i in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        keys.push(i);
      }
    }

    return keys;
  };
}
```